# Changing url name for web app

Tags: meteor

I am trying out Meteor, and every time I create and run a web app the url is localhost:3000; How do i change this url to whatever I want it to be?
for example, what would i do if I wanted the url of my web app to be www.gravity.com(random example)

Also, if I make a web app with meteor how do I add it to the chrome app store?
And finally, are there any good website to download free css website design templates?
* Sorry if I am asking a lot of "basic" questions, I have just started using meteor and I'm kind of a noob

Answer (score 1):

When you make an app with meteor, you're making it on a [local host](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). This means that the app is not up and running for everyone to see-- if someone else types in localhost:3000 from a different computer, your app will not pop up.

The easiest way to change this is to deploy with meteor--- meteor allows you to deploy to a website hosted on .meteor.com.

So if you want your url to be gravity.meteor.com, simply go to your project directory, and type 
`meteor deploy gravity.meteor.com`

If that name isn't taken, you or anyone else can access your app there.

However, if you do not want it to say ".meteor.com", and instead just want  www.gravity.com, you need to buy access to the domain www.gravity.com, and then deploy your app using a different method. You can buy a domain name from sites like godaddy.com. This is significantly harder than just deploying through .meteor.com. If that's something you want to do, here's a good tutorial on [deploying using digital ocean](http://meteortips.com/deployment-tutorial/).